# saving datetime to DB codeigniter always 1970

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

i have a code to save publish date in database, but it always changed to  1970/01/01 07:00 am
i use codeigniter framework and this is my view code

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Publish Date</label>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    <div class="input-group date form_datetime bs-datetime" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii">
                        <input type="text" name="form[date]" class="form-control" readonly="">
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button class="btn default date-reset" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button class="btn default date-set" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this my controller

```
$form = $this->input->post('form');
$data['PUBLISH'] = date('Y/m/d H:i a', strtotime($form['date']));
```

when i print `$form['date']`, the result is normal, but when i'm converting `$form['date']` in date format, it was error
where is the mistake?

Comment: What is the value and type for the date column in your database?

Comment: type : datetime
leght : 0

Comment: Ok thanks. I think the issue is with the `Y/m/d` since the usual method stored in db is YYYY-MM-DD with hyphens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your input name and array key are inconsistent("date" vs "dates").

Unix timestamps are relative to January 1, 1970 and hence that is the value of timestamp 0. An undefined array key will result in a value of null(and likely a notice/warning in the logs). `strtotime` will return false when the first parameter is null which will be cast to 0 when passed to `date` and hence the date of 1970/01/01.

**Edit**

From your additional information in the comments, the issue is that your provided date format is not recognized by `strtotime`. You will need to parse your expected format using a different method.

You can use [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to parse a specific format and then use [`DateTime::format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format) to store it in the desired format. For example:

```
$date=DateTime::createFromFormat("d F Y - H:i", $form["date"]);
$data["PUBLISH"]=$date->format("Y/m/d H:i a");
```

Comment: sorry i make mistake in my post, and i have been edited my post, but it still 1970 in result
i think the mistake is note in my view, because when i print $form['date] (before i change to format date) its work normally, but when i changed to format date, it error

Comment: Can you do a `var_dump` of $form['date'] and confirm the value there?

Comment: normal with no error
["date"]=> string(21) "13 April 2020 - 09:40"

Comment: That date format is not recognized by strtotime. It returns false.
`php > var_dump(strtotime("13 April 2020 - 09:40"));
bool(false)`

Comment: but when i print this 
var_dump(date('Y/m/d H:i a', strtotime($form['date'])));
the result is string(19) "1970/01/01 07:00 am"

Comment: and how to save in db ?

Comment: when i try to save in db without change the format, the data in db changed to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: You'll need to change the format, you'll just have to parse it in a different way. Take a look at `DateTime::createFromFormat`[https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php]